# Trouble With Functions

Tags: php, function, pdo

I am currently trying to make a script that will calculate page load time by using functions. I would really like to keep the PDO side of things to insert the data into a database.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
require 'common.php';
require 'page_load_statistics.php';

page_load_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Home</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php
//End The Page Load Statistics
page_load_end();
?>
```

**page_load_statistics.php**

```
<?php
 function page_load_start() {
   $time = microtime(true);
 }

 function page_load_end() {
   $query = "INSERT INTO page_statistics ( page_name, page_load_time ) VALUES(:page_name, :page_load_time ) ";        

   $page_name = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

   $page_load_time = (microtime(true) - $time);

   $query_params = array( ':page_name' => $page_name, ':page_load_time' => $page_load_time); 

    try 
        {  
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {  
        die("Failed to run query"); 
        } 
}
?>
```

**common.php**

```
    <?php 

    //Start Session Globally
        session_start();

    //PDO Connection & Settings
    $username = "private_info"; 
    $password = "private_info"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "private_info"; 

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    try 
    { 
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    {
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

 //UNDO Magic Quotes

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
            undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
            undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
            undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
        } 

//Define Content Type
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how I should be calling / writing the functions.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in page_load_statistics.php on line 15

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue.

Comment: Any recommendations on a fix or in a way I should be looking?

Comment: Try passing DB connection to both `function page_load_start($db)` and `function page_load_end($db)` see if that makes 'em kick into gear. Including `page_load_start($db);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is scope, as pointed out by @Fred-ii-. Your functions do not have access to the variables you have declared elsewhere, namely `$time` and `$db`.

Try this, and take note of the comments I added:

index.php:

```
<?php
  require 'common.php';
  require 'page_load_statistics.php';

  // store in a variable that will be sent to page_load_end
  $start_time = page_load_start(); 
?>

...html...

<?php
  //End The Page Load Statistics

  // Pass the DB object and the start time to this function
  page_load_end($db, $start_time);
?>
```

page_load_statistics.php:

```
<?php
 function page_load_start() {
    // return the start time so later you can set the 
    // start time with $start_time = page_load_start()
    return microtime(true); 
 }

 // Send to this function the DB object created in 'common.php', 
 // as well as the start time
 function page_load_end($db, $start_time) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO page_statistics ( page_name, page_load_time ) VALUES(:page_name, :page_load_time ) ";        

   $page_name = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

   $page_load_time = (microtime(true) - $start_time);

   $query_params = array( ':page_name' => $page_name, ':page_load_time' => $page_load_time); 

    try 
        {  
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {  
        die("Failed to run query"); 
        } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank You Mark! this worked for the most part except for now I am seeming to get a strange number in my time that is inserted into the database. page_load_time - 5.96046447754E-6

Comment: @Ruthless that means the site is taking 0.00000596 seconds to load. You may want to consider adjusting the column in the DB to be expressed in milliseconds (aka microtime*1000)

Comment: Yup @serakfalcon is correct - and as he pointed out a better approach might be to store milliseconds. For this, change each occurence of `microtime(true)` to `round(microtime(true)*1000)` .... note, `round` is not necessary, but it will give you a cleaner, albeit less accurate number, ie `1325` vs `1325.0571289062`. Up to you how you want to do it.